# Why is the value of my select reset itself after the html is copied?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a form inside of a `display: none;` div, so I can set all the checkboxes and other inputs before displaying them to the user.

The form is something like:

*Code Block #1*

```
<div class="hiddendiv" style="display:none;">
  <form id="someid">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" />
    <select id="selid">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
   </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

And then I set all the values, via JQuery:

*Code Block #2*

```
if(something){
    $('#check1').attr('checked', true);
}

if(something2){
    $('#check2').attr('checked', true);
}

if(something3){
    $('#check3').attr('checked', true);
}

$('#selid').val(5);
```

And then, finally, I move the html elsewhere:

*Code Block #3*

```
$('.some_div').html($('.hiddendiv').html());
```

All the check boxes display properly, based on whatever condition is used to set them. But the select is *always* set at the top-most position.

But... If I end *Code Block #2* with the following:

*Code Block #4*

```
alert($('#selid').val());
return;
```

The value in the alert box **IS** 5.

Moving the last two lines until after the reassign will always have the alert saying 1, and the select at the top-most position.

If I move the html (*Code Block #3*), and then follow up with:

```
$('.hiddendiv').remove();
$('#selid').val(5);
```

then it displays properly.

Being more specific with the selectors (i.e. `$('.hiddendiv #selid')` and `$('.some_div #selid')`) still has the same result.

**So what gives!?** Why is the select changing back to its top position, if I assign the value before moving it? I'm sure I've done this exact procedure before, and it worked just fine.

This file is being a little weird too. In another file on the same project, I set the checkboxes using `prop('checked', true);`, because the alternative doesn't work. But in this case, it's the exact opposite, and only `attr('checked', true);` is working.

The obvious hack, for now, is to assign the value after the move. But this isn't ideal and I would prefer to have it the way I've been trying for.

Thanks in advance for anything you come up with.

Comment: If your code is exactly as you describe then the problem is likely because you are appending elements with duplicated `id` attributes throughout the DOM, when they *have* to be unique.

Comment: Also note that you don't need the `if` statements in your second code block: `$('#check1').prop('checked', something); $('#check2').prop('checked', something2); ... `

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan good thought, but `something` isn't true/false, it's just an abbreviation for the longer condition I actually have in there. It's numerical, and 1->selected, 0->not. But `$('#check1').prop('checked', 0);` doesn't work. Gave it a shot, no dice. Good thought though, I would have been super stoked if it had just saved me 2/3 of the line count.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as per your first comment, I tried `var temp = $('.hiddendiv').html();  $('.hiddendiv').remove();  $('.some_div').html(temp);`, and that didn't work either. Anu's answer below works though.

Comment: `$('#check1').prop('checked', something==1);` works though! Thanks for the inspiration. Always looking to cut lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option's `selected` attribute

```js
$('#check1').attr('checked', true);
$('#selid option[value=5]').attr('selected',true);
$('.some_div').html($('.hiddendiv').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hiddendiv" style="display:none;">
  <form id="someid">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="check2" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="check3" />
    <select id="selid">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
   </select>
  </form>
</div>
  <div class="some_div"></div>
```